# Change image after click

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, html, onclick

I can't create simple gallery photos. After click to small image I need reload image in place for main image.

### gallery.js

```
imgArray = [  
  '../images/1.jpg',
  '../images/2.jpg',
  '../images/3.jpg',
  '../images/4.jpg',
  '../images/5.jpg',
  '../images/5.jpg'
];

function changeImage(nameOfImage){        
  document.getElementById('mainImage').src = imgArray[nameOfImage.id];
}
```

---

### html

```
<div align="center" class="mainImageDiv">
  <img id="mainImage" src="images/action/1.jpg" alt="1.jpg, 206kB" title="1" height="600" width="500">
</div>

<a href="#" id="1" onClick="changeImage(this)"><img src="images/action/min1.jpg" alt="min1.jpg, 18kB" title="min1" height="120" width="100" /></a>
<a href="#" id="2" onClick="changeImage(this)"><img src="images/action/min2.jpg" alt="min2.jpg, 18kB" title="min2" height="120" width="100" /></a>
```

Comment: The ID is a string. You could try using imgArry[parseInt(nameofImage.id,10)]

Comment: What is the question? you don't list any errors or unexpected results.

Comment: ParseInt doesn't works. Problem is, that after click to e.g. image with id="1" disappears image from element with id "mainImage" ... I want to change element "mainImage" after click other some other element .. in my case it's element with id "1" "2"

Comment: Is this actual code? Or is it just example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is the code you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/M2BSu/

```
var imgArray = [  
 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Brain_human_sagittal_section.svg/295px-Brain_human_sagittal_section.svg.png',
 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Solanum_muricatum_Flower_and_Fruit.jpg/220px-Solanum_muricatum_Flower_and_Fruit.jpg'
];

var counter = 0;
document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function () {  
    document.getElementById('mainImage').src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length]; 
    counter += 1;
}
```

**EDIT** It seems I misunderstood the problem. I guess the error is, as people commented, that your id is not a valid array index. You can use a real object instead, like this:

```
<a href="#" id="a_full_name" onClick="changeImage(this)">

var images = {
    'a_full_name': 'path to image',
    'another_img_id': 'path to this image'
};

function changeImage(anchor_object){   ... } // what you are passing is not the name of the image
```

And with that your code should work. Arrays are not very reliable in JavaScript (since they are not real arrays)

**EDIT**: Once found the problem, I give you this easy solution for your problem. As always, the simpler the better. Don't read any array or whatever, just get the path of the big image, from the path of the small image. You will not have to do any annoying maintenance in parallel of the html and the array. You just have to keep a consistent naming between the thumbnail and the big picture.

**html**
You don't really need an anchor element. If you want the pointer mouse, change the CSS

```
<img onClick="changeImage(this)" src="images/action/min1.jpg" title="min1" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changeImage(image_clicked){   // you pass the image object     
    var min_path = image_clicked.src;

    // adapt the path to point to the big image, in this case get rid of the "min"
    var big_path = min_path.replace("min", "");

    document.getElementById('mainImage').src = big_path;
}
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: nameOfImage is the element he wants to pass in. and .id is the id of that img.

Comment: Yeah, right. I updated the answer to propose a solution. Anyway, I find it a little bit "dirty" to use the id of an anchor to set the src of another image.

Comment: Thanks for advices, I found problem and problem was in link to my gallery in "imgArray" ... there should be only ONE DOTE before address. Thanks for all.

Comment: Hehehe, typical stupid error. Anyway, follow the KISS principle! I have updated my answer so that you can't have this kind of errors and you also don't have to maintain any array with the paths to the pictures.